# JWT Authorization header not reaching api

Tags: laravel, header, authorization, jwt, hosting

I deployed my laravel project on a shared hosting server that supports mod_rewrite and want to send a header called Authorization (JWT header) but it wont reach the controller.

mt .htaccess:

Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Which package for JWT are you using?

Comment: "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"

Comment: Guess you restarted the apache2 service after changing the htcaccess, right?

Comment: can I restart it even though I'm on a shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

To evade Apache2 discards the authorization header I needed to add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

To my .htcaccess file in my /public folder.

Comment: it still tells me that a token is absent